# Is there a way to decrease xbap application size?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, xbap

How can I decrease the deployed xbap application size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the deployed app footprint, not the memory footprint of the running app. A couple of thoughts:

- Decrease dependencies. Have you looked at the deployed app to see what your largest 3rd party dependencies are (framework assemblies aren't downloaded)?
- Build in Release mode. You'll lose line number info in exceptions, but your binaries will be smaller and you won't get pdbs included.

Answer (score 0):

Little addition to [nitzmahone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945423/is-there-a-way-to-decrease-xbap-application-size/1945465#1945465):

If you have resources (like images) - check that all of them is used in your app and think about decraasing count of it, or in images case you can adjust their quality.